# How to get results using a loop inside of switch map

Tags: rxjs, angular10

I have the next code, and it was working properly. to execute a request to my method `fetchDropdownDataByFederationId`, but now I have a requirement to execute the same method x number of times.

```
fetchInProgress(queryString?): Observable<IPerson[]> {
    let PersonList: IPerson[] = [];
    

    return this.getItems<IPerson[]>('', queryString).pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((wls: IPerson[]) => {

        PersonList = [...wls];
        //const createdbyIds = [...new Set(wls.map((f) => f.createdBy))];
        return this.teamPageService.getInformation(wls.createdBy);
        
      }),
            map((teams:any) => {
        console.log('> teams', teams);
        for (let i = 0; i < PersonList.length; i++) {
          //update information
        }

        //console.log('> Final value: ', PersonList);
        return PersonList;

      })
    );

  }
```

But, I'm not finding a way to execute my `SwitchMap` x number of times and get the results back to use them in my `map` method to parse the information.

I just moved my `SwitchMap` to `mergeMap`, something like this:

```
mergeMap((wls: IWalklist[]) => {
        //let allIds = wls.contact.map(id => this.getSingleData(id._id) );
        let drops: Dropdown[] = [];
        walklistList = [...wls];
        const allIds = [...new Set(wls.map((f) => f.createdBy))];
        return forkJoin(...allIds).pipe(
          map((idDataArray) => {
            drops.push(
              this.teamPageService.getInformation('');
            );
            return drops;
          })
        )
      }),
```

But still no luck.
Can some help me? how can I fix it?

Comment: I think your post is hard to follow, you tried to explain what you tried, but for me it is not really clear what exactly you want to achieve. Some model based explanation would be great.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of your code or what's going wrong ("But still not luck" <- that isn't very descriptive).